# Responsive images side by side, different height, centered

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am struggling with Bootstrap's responsive images. Here's the issue.

I would expect my three images on the fixed header to be responsive and to resize accordingly not only to themselves but also to their header container. This means the images should be smaller when the screen gets smaller, but the ratio to the navigation bar, which should also shrink with the new browser size, remains the same. I've illustrated the situation here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56bju7vu/1/).

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container" id="header">
    <div id="logoCont" class="logos"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://nationalband.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/137-80x80.png"/></div>
    <div id="cont2" class="logos"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Google-Drive-3.4-for-iOS-app-icon-small-55x55.png"/></div>
    <div id="cont3" class="logos"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://cruise-international.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/small-google-plus-icon-.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first picture is the logo and it should always be a bit larger than the navigation bar, also true when resizing the browser. The other two pictures should remain within the navigation bar even when resizing and should be centered vertically - with the same "space", possibly margin, to the top and to the bottom.

I am new to Bootstrap and I thought including the default class *img-responsive* would do the job, so I guess I must be doing something wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/56bju7vu/3/

Comment: Not quite, I've slightly modified my post to make the problem more comprehensible. First, I don't want them in three columns, placed just close to each other like in my example is fine. Second, I corrected the alignment to vertical, not horizontal (my mistake), they should be vertically centered inside the navigation bar, meaning having the same margin to the top and the bottom even when resizing the browser. Resizing should also make the three images smaller and still aligned as originally. I hope it is more clear now. I apologize if you worked in the wrong direction.